# How ClaimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated works in a real world app?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am a bit surprised about how the `ClaimsPrincipal` and `ClaimsIdentity` work in ASP.NET Core and came across a situation that is unclear to me:

- Can a `ClaimsIdentity` be authenticated (`IsAuthenticated`=True) and
  have `no` claims?
- Can a `ClaimsIdentity` not be authenticated
  (`IsAuthenticated`=False) `but have` claims?

I'm also not quite sure how `IsAuthenticated` works here: apparently only one type is queried.
https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/security/claims/ClaimsIdentity.cs

Answer (score 0):

The `AuthenticationType` property is read-only, so you can only make the `ClaimsIdentity` authenticated by sending it in when you construct it:

```cs
var authenticationType = "Signature";
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(authenticationType);
```

As you can see from the source you referenced, the `IsAuthenticated` property just checks that `m_authenticationType` exists.

So the answer to both your questions is "yes".

Comment: Yes, so far I could see this in the code. But the behavior is unclear for me and essential for unit tests. `When` the type is passed and what happens to the claims based on the type? I guess every authenticated claim has at least the NameIdentifier claim. And is an unauthenticated identity always without any claim?

Comment: It has nothing to do with claims, only whether there is an authentication type. And the authentication type can only be set from the constructor. So, in a unit test, just make sure you send in the authentication type when you are instantiating the `ClaimsIdentity` (as shown in the code above).

Comment: Thank you but that was not my question :-/ I asked about the *behavior* not how the single line of code works. When the type is passed by ASP.NET and when not? Will claims be set if the type is not passed? In other words, the interaction of authentication *and* claims.

Comment: No need to downvote. I answered both your questions ("yes" to both). As for how the claims behave, you can see from the source you referenced that both `m_instanceClaims` and `m_externalClaims` are always initialized to empty collections (unless claims are also sent in to the constructor). I'm not sure what the confusion could be here.